Navigating from one textField to other programatically using FocusState is not working
My requirement is that, I have one textField, onpressing it one keyboard will appear. In keyboard, the nextButton is pressed it should go to next textfield without dismissing the textField.I have tried with FocusState, but it is not working
import SwiftUI
enum placeholder {
    case email
    case password
    var description: String {
        return  switch self {
                case .email: "email"
                case .password: "password"
                }
    }
    var nextControll: String {
        return  switch self {
                case .email: "password"
                case .password: "email"
                }
    }
    
}
struct customTextField: View {
    var placeHolder: placeholder = .email
    @State var description: String = ""
    @FocusState var focusstate: String?

    var body: some View {
        TextField(placeHolder.description, text: $description)
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 50)
            .background {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12)
                    .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 2)
            }
            .focused($focusstate, equals: placeHolder.description)
            .onSubmit {
                focusstate = placeHolder.nextControll
            }
            .submitLabel(.next)
    }
}

struct TextFieldObservers: View {
    var placeholderView: placeholder?
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            customTextField(placeHolder: .email, description: "")
            customTextField(placeHolder: .password, description: "")
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 30)
    }
}

#Preview {
    TextFieldObservers()
}

See reference link: https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/xxvvo3/how_to_prevent_the_keyboard_hiding_after_i_click/?rdt=61416

Each of your customTextField's has own @FocusState, they don't share it with each other, your TextFieldObservers should have that focus state and text fields - receive it as a parameter. There are a lot of other options tow to organize it as well

tried ur solution, it worked.  Can you explain why?
PS: There is slight jerk in the keyboard animation, any solution not to occur.

First of all - focus control in SwiftUI is kinda a big troublemaker, things have to be setup 100% precise for everything to work properly, so yeah sometimes you just forget on minor thing and nothing works. About your case TextFieldObservers creates 2 independent customTextField's, both of them have own focus state and .focused($focusstate,) observes the change of view's own focus state, so when you set focus to toggle into another view you toggle only current view's focus state, this way you can dismiss the keyboard, but other view will never know that you did as you didn't modify its @fstate

I'd also recommend you to google something like "SwiftUI responder chain", as a lot of ppl faced that problem and (I hope) some solutions that they've found should be pretty nice
